# How to unsign signed cookie manually

Tags: django

I am using Django version 1.11.2 and using signed cookies for session store.

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
```

I am trying to unsign the cookie using python shell using:

```
from django.core import signing
signing.loads(".eJxVjk0.....J708kRdRvubY3RME")
```

but I get BadSignature error.

May be I am using the signing.loads in wrong way?

Comment: Can you show the dumps code as well?

Comment: @RajaSimon: I am not doing signing myself. It is being done by django signed cookie backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signing.loads` takes several more arguments, and you're only passing the first one correctly. If you look at how the `signed_cookies` backend loads keys, it does this:

```
signing.loads(
    self.session_key,
    serializer=self.serializer,
    max_age=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE,
    salt='django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies',
)
```

So you would need to mirror these arguments:

```
signing.loads(
    ".eJxVjk0.....J708kRdRvubY3RME",
    max_age=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE,
    salt='django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies',
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure looking at this code in the signed_cookies backend code, what the session_key should be. Did not realise that it is actually the signed value to be loaded. It works perfectly.